# mysql 'replace into' fails only on replication slave

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

The purpose of this table is to collect multiple stats (specified by `name` column) by-the-minute, and then I wrote some sql that rolls up the sum( ) of the minutes into the hours by name, and the sum( ) of hours into days, etc.

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `time_name` (`time`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=32060002 ;
```

Here's one of the errors given by "show slave status":

```
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry '32189722' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'quip_mailer'. Query: 'replace into stats select NULL, date_format( execute_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ), 'sent', count(*) as v from queue as q where execute_time > '2013-07-13 16:17:00' group by date_format( execute_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ) order by date_format( execute_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' )'
```

The error is the primary key, although as you can see the primary key passed in is NULL.

And then why wouldn't "replace" actually kick in and replace the data anyway? Doesn't make sense to me.

If I copy/paste run that exact sql command on the slave, works just fine. Only when it's coming down from replication does it have a problem.

Comment: Is it the time value or the primary key causing the duplicate key error?  Also, are you 100% sure that the table on the slave server is empty when you try to run the `REPLACE` query?

Comment: primary key. I went ahead and had it give me one of the errors and then added it to the question above. Also added the note that the exact command works just fine on the slave, just doesn't work when it comes through replication.

Answer (score 0):

Log on to the slave server and verify that the auto-increment value on it is equal to or above the current highest value on your master.  What is likely happening is that the auto-increment value has somehow gotten out of synch between the master and the slave.   Once you know slave's auto increment value, you can `ALTER TABLE` the master and set the auto increment start value to a safe number that is higher than the auto increment value on the slave.

Comment: This was on a fresh dump from master and load to slave. As soon as the slave caught up with the master the problem started happening. The autoincrement is correct.